# Several labels in for loop

Tags: html, django, pycharm

I'm pretty new in programming and I did the Django tutorial 'Writing your first Django app'. Now I want to make some changes to this app and I do not really know how to do it.
I want to set several labels with different images for each choice.id in the following input for loop:

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

view.py

```
   def index(request):
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
        context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


    def detail(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


    def results(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})


    def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
            # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
            # user hits the Back button.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

I'd really appreciate some help about this.
Thanks!

Comment: Please also post your models.py and view.py.

Comment: Ok. it's done. Thanks!

Comment: By labels you mean? And are these labels the same for each choice?

Comment: I want to list different images to select for each choice, and then submit